# How do I return an instance of my base object simply?

Tags: swift

I have a subclass and I want to be able to return an instance of its superclass. This doesn't work:

```
func baseTransaction()->Transaction {
    return super
}
```

Can I return a base class in a simple way like this or do I need to create an instance and copy in all the appropriate properties? In the past I've done just that, but thought I would see if there's a way to do it more simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "return an instance of its superclass" I presume you mean "return this class instance as if it were its superclass" - in that case you have to return the instance itself:

```
func baseTransaction() -> Transaction {
    return self
}
```

If you have a `Transaction` class, and create a `SubTransaction` subclass:

```
class SubTransaction : Transaction { ... }
```

then any instance of `SubTransaction` is also an instance of `Transaction`, hence assignable to any variable (or which can be passed as argument) of type `Transaction`.

Note that a subclass may override the implementation of the base class, while keeping the same interface (or extending it). If that is what you want to avoid, and you need a true instance of the base class, then the only way is creating a new instance. Presumably you have to create a copy constructor in the base class, and then obtain a superclass copy with a function like:

```
func baseTransaction() -> Transaction {
    return Transaction(self)
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that still be a SubTransaction class just cast as a Transaction? I could still cast it to SubTransaction if I wanted to.

Comment: So either way I'm copying property values. That's what I figured, I just wanted to see if there was an easier way with a new language.

Comment: That kind of problem is rare :) usually it's about turning an instance of a base class into an instance of a subclass - although I think it has to be done in the same way